# Where can I find some interesting quant trading questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm preparing for a quant interview and want some more practice problems. Is there a way to find a lot of them easily on this website?

Comment: Maybe there is something on [stats.se] the site about statistics.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off trying [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/). Quantitative finance questions are often not well received on this site.

Comment: I'm interviewing for entry level positions. The questions are not specific to finance at all, and mainly are just brain-teasers, probability/counting, and strategy style questions

Comment: @Goldname I actually have a quant finance job. The interview questions were mostly probability theory and stochastic calculus, but finance knowledge was expected. Coming from a pure math PhD, nobody wanted me due to the lack of that knowledge. I ended up getting a programming job at a financial company, excelled, then applied for a quant finance job at the same company. Observing my colleagues interview others, I wouldn't have gotten the job applying directly.

Comment: Which company are you at?  Jane Street and HRT explicitly said no financial knowledge was required

Comment: @Goldname Jane Street usually sends some materials beforehand if you get an interview. The questions tend to be probability/combo and phrased as games. Try looking at glassdoor and maybe searching some of the questions to see if they've been asked here.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber The material they send is not related to quant finance except for one terminology section. I've looked through glassdoor, but it's a bit lacking and they didn't post the solutions

Comment: @Gold Alexander is saying find the problems there, find the solutions here.